# Remove duplicate columns in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, paperclip

I am had Paperclip gem in my app then I removed it and I wanna add it back again. However, I am getting this error when I try to `rake db:migrate`:

```
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddAttachmentImageToPosts (20170115210207)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
== 20170115210207 AddAttachmentImageToPosts: migrating ========================
-- change_table(:posts)
   (0.9ms)  ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" character varying
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "image_file_name" of relation "posts" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" character varying
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:423:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:443:in `column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in attachment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `each_pair'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `block in attachment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `attachment'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20170115210207_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb:4:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:363:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20170115210207_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "image_file_name" of relation "posts" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" character varying
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:423:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:443:in `column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in attachment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `each_pair'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `block in attachment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `attachment'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20170115210207_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb:4:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:363:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20170115210207_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "image_file_name" of relation "posts" already exists
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:423:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:443:in `column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in attachment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `each_pair'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:52:in `block in attachment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/schema.rb:51:in `attachment'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20170115210207_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb:4:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:363:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20170115210207_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I ran `rails c` this is what I got:

```
 2.3.0 :001 > Post.column_names
     => ["id", "title", "link", "description", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "cached_votes_total", "cached_votes_score", "cached_votes_up", "cached_votes_down", "cached_weighted_score", "cached_weighted_total", "cached_weighted_average", "image"]
```

I know that there is a way to remove the "image_file_name" duplication but I am not really aware of how to do so to my app. I did find some posts that are similar to my problem but nothing really solved it!

Comment: If you already have that field why are you trying to add it again?

Comment: Because when I removed Paperclip before.. I also deleted Its migration too

Comment: comment your model where you have added attachment,any validation... and then run migration file..

Comment: @Milind I did this but now I am getting this error `Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'`

Comment: you have required attribute in some other models..search entire project for image_file_name and i am sure..you will get it..and then comment it out and re run migration and then again uncomment it .

Answer (score 1):

Because you deleted the migration for creating the column, and if you create a migration to delete it, it will cause error in other environment(production), as there is no column to be deleted at first place.

Assuming you haven't deploy the migration to production.
You can just drop the column directly in database console.

run `rails dbconsole`

and

```
ALTER TABLE posts DROP COLUMN image_file_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never just remove a migration. If you want to remove a field you should create a new migration for it.

You have 2 options now, or you can `rake db:migration:reset` that will recreate your entire database OR you can comment the content on this last migration, run `rake db:migrate` and after that you can uncomment it.

Comment: I did the second option, and it ran the db:migrate. However, when I try to upload a picture, I get this `Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'`

Comment: Should I try `rake db:migration:rest` now?